# User input being limited to the alphabet in python

Tags: python

I am SUPER new to programming and have my first assignment coming up in python. I am writing a hangman type game, where users are required to guess the word inputted from the other user.

I have written most of the code, but the only problem I am having is when users have to input the word, making sure it is only limited to the alphabet. The code I have so far is :

```
word = str.lower(raw_input("Type in your secret word! Shhhh... "))

answer = True

while answer == True:
    for i in range(len(word)):
         if word[i] not in ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
             word = raw_input("Sorry, words only contain letters. Please enter a word ")
             break

         else:
             answer = False
```

This works while I input a few tries, but eventually will either exit the loop or displays an error. Is there any easier way to use this? We've really only covered topics up to loops in class, and break and continue are also very new to me. Thank you! (Pardon if the code is sloppy, but as I said I am very new to this....)

Comment: Just FYI, `while answer:` is an equivalent check, and much more Pythonic.

Comment: what's the error it displays?

Comment: It's only equivalent when answer is a bool

Comment: @simonzack: it's always equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

This will work, too - as long as you don't mind having upper and lowercase characters

```
if word[i].isalpha():
```

To make things even simpler, as suggested in the comments:

```
if word.isalpha():
```

In this way, you don't have to iterate over each character, just check the whole word

Comment: Or just `if word.isalpha()` without the loop.

Comment: @DangerCat you're welcome! if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)